# Turn a single partylist field into multiple

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there a way to transform a partylist field like **Customer** in a **Campaign Response** to allow for multiple Contacts/Accounts/Leads?

Although unsupported, I now from [Jian Wang](http://jianwang.blogspot.com/2008/05/mysterious-crm-lookup-i.html) that some attributes of the lookup can be modified in the *onload()* event like this:

```
crmForm.all.customer.setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1,2");
```

Is there a similiar attribute that would turn this into a field that allows multiple participants like the **To** field in an e-mail?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an easy (though unsupported) way of doing this. It doesn't require Javascript code, by the way. I just exported the entity CampaignResponse and edited the XML. Then searched the attribute (Customer) and element LookupStyle

```
<attribute PhysicalName="Customer">
...
<LookupStyle>single</LookupStyle>
...
</attribute>
```

Changed the value to ***multi***

```
<attribute PhysicalName="Customer">
...
<LookupStyle>multi</LookupStyle>
...
</attribute>
```

Reimported, and it worked!